Customizing Apps List in Anaconda Navigator
I am going through a beginner's course for Python and for the course I only need Jupyter Notebook in the list of apps. It's a bit annoying that, every time I want to open a Notebook to do my course, I have to click on the Applications dropdown to filter just the Installed Applications, scroll down to Jupyter, and then click on that. Okay, I know: Two extra clicks?!? Oh, so much time and effort wasted! ;) But I thought it'd be a good small lesson to learn about managing Channels in Navigator, so I did some digging. I found some documentation on docs.anaconda about Channels, but what I found there I didn't see how to apply that to what I want to do: Just have ONLY Jupyter Notebook listed when I first open Navigator. Maybe that's not possible, but I thought I'd check.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
